# If I want to conduct analysis using a quartile, what is the correct way to say this?

Tags: statistics

Do I "use a quartile" or do I "use quartiles"? Is "use" even the correct word?

Do I need to be more wordy and say "use quartile summary statistics?"

Should I say "use quartile analysis" or something like that?

EDIT:
We have a large team of reviewers reviewing a large group of applicants. Each applicant will be ranked by each reviewer using a number scale. When completed we will **use a quartile** to analyze the ranking.

Comment: Far too little context to say one way or another.

Comment: @cgmil context added

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: @Pang my bad, I somehow thought I was on stack exchange, but it's totally obvious to me now that this is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "use a quartile" is not the best way to write that sentence in the end. I'm not sure what data you are computing quartiles from, and the singular use seems to fly in the face of the plural nature of the rest of the paragraph. I'm going to assume that you compute quartiles over all ratings, and I would rewrite the previous sentence like so:

"When completed, we will compute the rankings' quartiles and use them to analyze the rankings."